# Add paragraph in wp-login page with jquery

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I need to add some custom text in the wp-login.php page of my Wordpress website. My idea is to use some custom jQuery (by Custom code settings in Theme Options) like this:

```js
(function($) {
$(document).ready( function() {
  $('#nav').after('<p>some text</p>');
});
})(jQuery);
```

The #nav id is the paragraph after the login form in wp-login.php

There is no result. Do you have any ideas? Is it possible to customize wp-login.php with some custom code?

Comment: Try using a document.ready handler instead of an IIFE: https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/. It's likely your current code is running before the DOM has loaded.

Comment: In that case can you please edit the question to include the correct code, and ideally the relevant HTML too

Comment: Thank you Rory, but it doesn't work anyway.

Comment: Since you're using wordpress, how do you use your javascript? I mean which action/filter hook did you use to inject your javascript onto the page?

Comment: Hi @Ruvee, by custom code settings in theme options. Usually works everytime.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following steps to make sure your custom code works:

1. Create a `javascript file` in your theme directory or in a sub-directory in the root directory of your theme, and call it, let's say, `your_custom_js_code.js`.
2. Then, use an `action hook` called `login_enqueue_scripts` to enqueue/load your javascript files onto the right page at the right moment. (i.e wp-login.php)
3. Then enqueue/load `jquery` onto the page.
4. And finally, enqueue/load your custom code onto the page.

---

1- Your custom jquery code: (This code goes into your javascript file)

```js
jQuery(document).ready($ => {
  $('#nav').after('<p>some text</p>');
});
```

2, 3, 4- Use `login_enqueue_scripts` action hook to load  both `jquery` and your custom jquery file onto the right page at the  right moment: (This code goes into the `functions.php` of your theme)

> Note, that i've created `your_custom_js_code.js` in a sub-folder in my theme root directory called `js`. So the path to that file would be `get_theme_file_uri('/js/your_custom_js_code.js')`. If you decide to create your custom javascript file elsewhere, then feel free to change the path, used in the following snippet, accordingly.

```php
add_action("login_enqueue_scripts", "your_custom_jquery");

function your_custom_jquery()
{
  wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
  wp_enqueue_script('your-custom-jquery-code', get_theme_file_uri('/js/your_custom_js_code.js'), 'JQuery', microtime(), TRUE);
}
```

Let me know if you were able to get it to work!